# Convert data type of percent fields to number in Carto Builder

Tags: carto

I have a dataset in Carto Builder with a column that lists percentage values with a percent symbol (e.g. "10%", "50%", "35%"). By default Carto has categorized the fields in this column as strings. I want to use this column to apply shading to a choropleth map based on percent. Is there any way to get Builder to process this column numerically?

If I try to convert the data type of the column from String to Number all the fields become null. I can do the conversion in my source program but I am looking for a way to do this all in Carto Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using simple SQL:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  substring(string_field FROM '[0-9]+')::numeric as num_field 
FROM
  table_name
```

Remember to apply this query to the node data source. If you have some analysis attached, you would need to drag that node out. More about `substring` Postgres function [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html), and BUILDER analysis workflow [here](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/analysis-tips-and-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove % char. I'd try these two options, replace table and field names with yours:

a) before changing field type remove them with `update <table> set <field> = rtrim(<field>,'%')`

b) use custom SQL to get data, something like `select *,to_number(<field> ,'999%') from <table>`